# vuejs config multiple data source

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have two data table in vue app.

- Cash [code, description,cash]
- Upload [bank, id]

For my update function, i need to take [bank, id] from upload and [cash] from cash. 
i don't know how, can someone help please ?  Thank you. 
 This is my code:

```
  var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
cash: {
        codeentry:'',
        description:'',
        cash:'',      
 },
 upload: {
        bank:'',
        id:'',       
 },
 methods: {               
 updateBank:function(){
     axios.put('/updatebank', this.upload)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.etat) {
                    this.upload = {
                        id:response.data.etat.id,
                        bank:response.data.etat.bank,
                    };
                       this.cash = {
                          cash: response.data.etat.cash,      
                    };  
                }

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('errors: ', error)
            })
    },
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the function in your back end to accept an object containing both the upload and cash, so the first line of your `updateBank` method on the front end will look like:

```
axios.put('/updatebank', { this.upload, this.cash })
```